# notifyDataSetChanged not working properly on fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore, notifydatasetchanged

As described in the title; I find myself unable to get the desired fragment to update properly.

I have a fragment that shows notifications to the user, and it should be updated every time a document gets added to the class/database. However, when I delete the document manually from the database, the class does not seem to be updated and it shows the documents previously found in the database. Additionally, it does, however, show the current documents if I open and close the application.

Fragment:

```
public class NotificationFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

private RecyclerView mNotificationList;
private NotificationsAdapter notificationsAdapter;
private List<Notifications> mNotifList;
private FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;


public NotificationFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification, container, false);


    mNotifList = new ArrayList<>();

    mNotificationList = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.notification_list);
    notificationsAdapter = new NotificationsAdapter(getContext(), mNotifList);


    mNotificationList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mNotificationList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(container.getContext()));
    mNotificationList.setAdapter(notificationsAdapter);

    mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    String current_user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mFirestore.collection("Users").document(current_user_id).collection("Notifications").addSnapshotListener(requireActivity(), new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (documentSnapshots != null && !documentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                        Notifications notifications = doc.getDocument().toObject(Notifications.class);
                        mNotifList.add(notifications);
                        notificationsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    });


    return v;
}
```

Database Structure:

[image: Database Structure]

Comment: Probably you need to check for `if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED)` in your `onEvent`

Comment: Please add your database structure and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo my database structure is as follow: Users/“User id”/Notifications/. Inside “Notifications/“ I store all the documents inside this collection for each user. Please let me know if this is what you are referring. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't help. Please add a screenshot of it.

Comment: @AlexMamo I added the screenshot, but it does not seem to be showing.

Comment: Have you tried ישו אוהב אותך solution by using `DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED`?

Comment: @AlexMamo well, aside from not updating after a document is removed, the fragment will not update when a document is added. I have to close the application for it to refresh. Additionally, I added what  ישו אוהב אותך suggested and it is still not refreshing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below given method inside your NotificationsAdapter.class and then call this method instead of calling notifyDataSetChanged() directly in your Fragment. Actually you are not passing data to the Adapter that was the issue.

```
public void updateAdapter(ArrayList<Notifications> mDataList) {
        this.mList = mDataList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: I did as you mention, but whenever I call the method in my fragment it gives me an error. Below is how I have the code in both the fragment and adapter. Adapter : public void updateAdapter(ArrayList<Notifications> mDataList) {
        this.mNotifList = mDataList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }     Fragment : notificationsAdapter.updateAdapter();

Comment: You missed the paramater in method. Use like this notificationsAdapter.updateAdapter(mNotificationList);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove any data set you have to set notifyItemRemoved with position of the data.

Example:

```
mDataset.remove(position); // remove your data
notifyItemRemoved(position); // notify that your data is removed
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataSet.size()); // you can use if range is changed
```

Comment: are you referring in the RecyclerViewAdapter?